# All my code runs twice when compiled by Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I build my js bundle with webpack using `webpack-dev-server` my code runs twice every time. Not sure how to fix it.

[Screenshot of Developer Tools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz5IV.png)

My webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-eval-sourcemap',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    path.join(__dirname, '../src/main')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.html')
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.join(__dirname, '../assets'),
        to: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/assets')
      }
    ])
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    outputPath: '/lol',
    hot: true
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, '../src')
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: I've been seeing the same behavior for a while. It feels like a regression somewhere along the way. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the configuration as it's similar to what I use. You can get the same behavior if you run the dev server in inline mode (`inline: true` + drop those dev server related entries). I guess we would have to dig into the code to solve this.

Comment: This could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447858/webpack-adding-duplicates-of-runtime-into-bundle/37466820#37466820 .

Answer (score 94, accepted):

in the template file you might have manually added a  loading the bundle.

If you don't have the

```
inject: false
```

option in

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.html')
}),
```

the bundle will get added again.

Comment: This works! No more double initialization! Only thing is I'm seeing style changes when "inject: false". Any insight on why that would be?

Comment: "style changes when" ... maybe css declarations were stepping on each other when loaded twice ?

Comment: This works, certainly, but it might be more direct to remove the template's `<script src="index.js"></script>` tag that is the likely cause of the double inclusion.

Comment: Do note that if you are using Webpack (from scratch) with React, you must also remove `<React.StrictMode>` from `index.js`

Answer (score 9):

Expanding a bit on @[Emil Perhinschi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152612/emil-perhinschi)'s and @[ggloren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6243352/ggorlen)'s earlier replies ...

Alternatively, if your `../src/index.html` file does not rely on any script other than `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`, simply remove the latter from your index.html.

Per https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin, the default for `inject` is `true` and ...

> When passing `true` or `'body'` all javascript resources will be
>   placed at the bottom of the body element.

Thus your two instantiations of bundle.js are:

1. The `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` that you (presumably) coded, and
2. HtmlWebpackPlugin's injection "at the bottom of the body element".