# Webpack adding duplicates of runtime into bundle

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

Does anyone know why I am getting duplicates of the webpack runtimes in the bundle?

It's adding multiple numbers after the ? and the browser is seeing them as new files.

- dev-server.js?
- dev-server.js?52d4
- dev-server.js?53d4*

[image: webpack-dupes]

See the file tree on the left:
[image: webpack-dupes2]

Why is it doing this? I just want one copy of the file in the bundle.

Comment: Do you have multiple entries in your configuration? Reading from the webpack-dev-server code it creates a server/client pair per each entry. That could be one explanation.

Comment: Interesting. I do have 3 entry points in my webpack config, and I'm getting 3 duplicates. Let me check that and update.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I would expect to see. Here's the [code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/a77eac516dace7f5072740206eda474a8141055b/bin/webpack-dev-server.js#L248) that does that.

Comment: I'm guessing each of your entries points at **jwt-decode**. Hence those warnings.

Comment: You are right! I combined my 3 entry points into 1 file, and made it 1 entry point, and no more duplication! If you make an answer I'll give you the credit. Now I just wonder why he wrote the code to put those duplicates, do you think we should make a pull request to modify that so it doesn't duplicate the codes?

Comment: It was a [bug fix](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/commit/a4ec2a94f62cdf6c1e7ecfd7cb7ef7a7bae9b17e) by the looks of it so I'm thinking the lines are there for a purpose. I'll set up an answer based on all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack sets up a client/server pair for each `entry` by design. That's why you are seeing all of those prints. Given each entry happens to depend on **jwt-decode**, you also get those warnings.

Here's the [relevant code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/a77eac516dace7f5072740206eda474a8141055b/bin/webpack-dev-server.js#L248). The code was introduced as a part of a [bug fix](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/commit/a4ec2a94f62cdf6c1e7ecfd7cb7ef7a7bae9b17e).