# Webpack dev server bootstrapping twice

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

Webpack dev server is bootstrapping twice for an unknown reason. (Note that only the dev-server has this problem, if I bundle the files, everything runs ok).

I'm seeing this line executing twice:

```
// Load entry module and return exports
  return hotCreateRequire(790)(__webpack_require__.s = 790);
```

I can also see this line two times in my browser log:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
```

These are the used versions

```
"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.21"
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.4",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All my code runs twice when compiled by Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081559/all-my-code-runs-twice-when-compiled-by-webpack)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was using HtmlWebpackPlugin,

using

```
inject: false
```

Did the magic as stated in this question:

[All my code runs twice when compiled by Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081559/all-my-code-runs-twice-when-compiled-by-webpack)

Comment: This works! But it changes the styles a little. Any insight on why that would be?

Comment: Maybe a problem related with the entry poin of your files @zero_cool. Maybe the css files are loaded in a different way.