# Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I try and use a hook in my app, I get the `Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component` error. I'm using a standard webpack4/babel config, with `preset-env` and `preset-react` plugins. My react/react-dom versions are pinned to `16.8.4` using yarn resolutions, so there should not be a mismatch in React/dom versions.

This is on the most basic of usages:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function MyComp() {
  const [hello] = useState(0);

  return <div>HELLO {hello}</div>;
}
export default MyComp;
```

I have checked the gotchas listed https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html with no luck.

Is there anything else that I need to include?

Stack Snippet version from T.J. Crowder (which works):

```js
const { useState } = React;

function MyComp() {
  const [hello] = useState(0);

  return <div>HELLO {hello}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComp />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: Debugging the error reveals that

```js
function resolveDispatcher() {
  var dispatcher = ReactCurrentDispatcher.current;
  !(dispatcher !== null) ? invariant(false, 'Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. (/* omitted url due to warning */ )') : void 0;
  return dispatcher;
}
```

in `react.development` such that `dispatcher` is null. Would this still suggest that I am not using the correct version of React/DOM, even though `yarn list` informs me that they're both at 16.8.4?

EDIT2: `console.log`-ing a count in the parent's render function reveals

```js
let count = 0;
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    count++;
    console.log("counter", count++);

    return (
      <MyComp />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Actually runs twice:

```
VM239 bundle.js:141088 counter 1
App.js:46 counter 1
```

which is *very* interesting - I can't explain why that would occur (my app had otherwise ran fine before I tried this experiment - but it would suggest that there could be two competing processes in conflict

Comment: Please show how you use `MyComp`. If you call `MyComp()` directly as a function react will complain.

Comment: I dropped your code into a Stack Snippet (making the very minor changes required to do that) and it works just fine. Please update the snippet I've added for you to show what you're really doing so we can help you understand why it wasn't working.

Comment: Double check that you have the correct versions of react *and* react-dom installed.

Comment: I am indeed calling the component using standard JSX syntax, <MyComp />. Indeed, the code snippet you have kindly creates works for me as well. I have updated my question with some more information about my findings.

Comment: Does `yarn list` list what's written in the `package.json` or does it look at what's actually installed on your system? Directly look at `node_modules/react/package.json` and `node_modules/react-dom/package.json`.

Comment: It is the equivalent of `npm ls` - I'm not certain of what it actually does - although it is likely that it would read the package.json. It will however also list any copies of the package which exist, for example if they are brought in via other dependencies. I have confirmed that both react and react-dom are at 16.8.4, without any other versions present

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was with my webpack config - I was using both the HtmlWebpackPlugin whilst adding the output bundle's script tag to my index.html, as described here: [All my code runs twice when compiled by Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081559/all-my-code-runs-twice-when-compiled-by-webpack)

This meant that React was being included twice, causing the error. Sadly, all of my previous checks were over different versions, not 2 instances of the same version!

Comment: Good catch, well-explained question and nice follow up.