# Webpack showing duplicate console logs

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler

[ss of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McvHX.png)

Anyone knows why webpack 5 is showing 2 console logs. Please help

Comment: Because it wants to notify you of two different things? Also, it's webpack-dev-server, not Webpack itself.

Comment: I checked multiple times it shows duplicate of the every log. Any solution to turn it for webpack-dev-server

Answer (score 0):

PiSet - I had this same issue and it is annoying.  to resolve it I added inject: false to my HTMLWebpackPlugin as found in this [All my code runs twice when compiled by Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081559/all-my-code-runs-twice-when-compiled-by-webpack) question.

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
    }),
  ],
```